# How would one interpret these regression coefficients?

Tags: interpretation, regression-coefficients

I ran a regression with the following equation:
y ~ x*s + controls
y is the percentage change in profits (from a baseline value) for each company over t weeks.
x is the percentage of minorities in each company
s is a dummy variable that equals to one on dates of lockdown and equals to zero otherwise.

The coefficients I get from the regression are:
intercept: 0.1846***
x: 0.03741**
s: -0.2465***
xs: 0.1846***

Would this mean that a one percentage point increase in minorities leads to a 18% increase in profits? Or is it that a one percentage point increase in minorities from the mean leads to a 18% increase in profits from the mean?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the coefficients for the intercept, x, s and the interaction.  The 0.16 relates to how different the effect of x is on y at different levels of s, and, likewise, how different the effect of s is on y at different levels of x, but it will be easier to answer with all the coeffiicents.

Comment: You can put these it table format, if you want, using the formatting commands.

Comment: intercept: 0.1846***
x: 0.03741**
s: -0.2465***
x*s: 0.1846***

Comment: Add this to your question. Don't provide info in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You have

$y = 0.1846 + 0.03741x   -0.2465s + 0.1846xs$

You can now get predicted values of y from plugging number into the equation (statistics packages will do this for you).

- The 0.18 is the predicted value of the change in profits when x = 0 and s = 0.
- The 0.037 is the effect of a one point increase in x, when s = 0.
- The -0.25is the effect of a one point increase in s, when x = 0.
- The (second) 0.18 is the interactive effect.

(It does seem odd that the intercept and the interaction have exactly the same parameter estimate; not sure what is going on there).